# Allcoin signed POST request fails

Tags: python, api, post, md5

The API i am using requires an MD5 encryption to work on POST requests. I am trying the make an 'userBalance' request to the API using the documentation https://www.allcoin.ca/api_market/market But every time it gives me back {'code': 1, 'msg': '签名校验失败'} (which means signature check failed). The API only asks for 2 parameteres, the api_key and sign. I carefully follow the guidance of the documentation, but the API still rejects the POST. Any suggestions why it fails the signature check? Am i missing something?

```
import hashlib
import keys
import requests

KEY = keys.allcoin["key"]
API_SECRET = keys.allcoin["secret"]

msg = "api_key='{}&secret_key={}".format(KEY, API_SECRET)
signature = hashlib.md5(msg.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

parameters = {
    "api_key": KEY,
    "sign": signature.upper(),
}

params = "&".join("{}={}".format(a, b) for a, b in parameters.items())
url = "http://www.allcoin.ca/Api_User/userBalance"
r = requests.post(
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'
    },
    url=url,
    params=parameters
)
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change `params=parameters` to `params=params` in your `requests.post()`.

Comment: Hello @Colin thanks for the reply! requests creates the same url output for both aproaches. I still tried your suggestion though, nothing..